# make ndarray containg string and int

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

How to make ndarray by reading from a csv file like

```
12,employed,32,happy,1
21,unemployed,31,poor,0
34,rich,45,unhapppy,0
```

NOTE: file can be very large

output array:

```
[[12,"employed",32,"happy",1]
 [21,"unemployed",31,"poor",0]
 [34,"rich",45,"unhapppy",0]]
```

while reading from csv file using `np.genfromtxt(filename,delimiter = ",",dtype = None)` it make the 1-d array of tuples and with `dtype = int` it make strings a Nan

Comment: It's not a 1D array of tuples. It's a structured array (of shape 3 with 5 columns) which will be faster (much faster) than a "normal array" of `object`s or just having a `pandas.DataFrame`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) first and then [`DataFrame.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) for convert to `numpy array`:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('file', header=None)
print(df)
    0           1   2         3  4
0  12    employed  32     happy  1
1  21  unemployed  31      poor  0
2  34        rich  45  unhapppy  0

arr = df.values
print(arr)
[[12 'employed' 32 'happy' 1]
 [21 'unemployed' 31 'poor' 0]
 [34 'rich' 45 'unhapppy' 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create structured arrays with combined data type. NumPy array unlike list cannot contain different data types. All elements of NumPy array have to be the same data type.

```
import numpy as np

dt = np.dtype([("iq",     np.uint8),
               ("status", np.unicode_, 32),
               ("age",    np.uint8),
               ("mood",   np.unicode_, 32),
               ("flag",   np.bool_)])

a = np.loadtxt("file.csv", dtype=dt, delimiter=",")

print(a)
print(a[1:]["status"])
print(a[["age", "mood"]])
```